# How to resolve Bad encoding in X509 Certificate issue in jdk1.6

Tags: java, ssl, java-7, java-6, apache-tomee

I am getting below excpetion in jdk1.6.But same it's working JDK1.7 version onwards.
So is this problem with JDK1.6 version?

```java
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: java.io.IOException: Bad encoding in X509 Certificate
at sun.security.provider.certpath.OCSP.check(OCSP.java:219)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.OCSP.check(OCSP.java:85)
at com.strutsrecipes.antbuild.business.PIOCSPValidation.generateCertificatePath(PIOCSPValidation.java:67)
at com.strutsrecipes.antbuild.actions.LoginSearchAction.execute(LoginSearchAction.java:21)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:480)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
```